# Performance Improvement On joining Date Fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to join large table on Look up Calendar table.  I have to compare the dates and get the result. My Code looks like below

```
select distinct MemberID,AuthID,Carrier,ServiceStatus
,COALESCE([DischargeDate],'1900-01-01'),Provider#,ProviderName
,CAST(dateadd(day,-1,c.pkdate) AS date) as DailyDate
from Table1 a
inner join [dbo].[Calendardays] c
on cast([servicedate] as date) <= CAST(dateadd(day,-1,c.pkdate) AS date)
  AND CAST([serviceenddate] AS date) >= CAST(dateadd(day,-1,c.pkdate) AS date)
```

I have created index on Service date and Service end date. Even then performance is really slow because of row by row checking.

Is there a better way of doing such joins which results faster?

Comment: the main issue is your casting and dateadd usage on join clauses

Comment: I would suggest adding sample data, desired results, and explaining what you are trying to do.  I would actually suggest asking another question with this information.

Comment: Your indexes don't mean much when you are casting everything in your ON clause. Perhaps store your dates as dates so you can take advantage of your index without band-aiding it and you aren't running to the CPU with every record to see what it will convert to before joining. That's expensive.